# Let $ u(x,y,z) $ be differentiable function. Calculate sum of derivatives

Tags: analysis

Let $ u(x,y,z)= \frac{1}{12}x^4 - \frac{1}{6}x^3(y+z)+ \frac{1}{2}x^2yz + f(y-x,z-x) $

where $ f - $ any differentiable function.

Calculate $ \frac{\delta u}{\delta x} + \frac{\delta u}{\delta y} + \frac{\delta u}{\delta z}$

Solution: Well im strugling with part with "any differentiable function". I know that i have to calculate three partial derivatives, but i have problem with $ f(y-x,z-x) $. What is that mean in this situation? I can assume for example $ p=y-x, q=z-x $ then $ f(p,q) = p+q $ (because 
linear function is differentiable in every point, so sum of linear functions is also differentiable), so we have $ f(p,q) = p+q = y-x+z-x= -2x + y + z$, and now i have to complete

$ \frac{\delta f(p,q)}{\delta x} , \frac{\delta f(p,q)}{\delta y} , \frac{\delta f(p,q)}{\delta z}$ and complete this simple 
derivatives $ \frac{\delta u}{\delta x} , \frac{\delta u}{\delta y} , \frac{\delta u}{\delta z}$ , and then just sum up everything $ \frac{\delta u}{\delta x} + \frac{\delta u}{\delta y} + \frac{\delta u}{\delta z}$

Please give me a hint, because this is propably wrong.

Comment: Note that $f[\vec g(x,y,z)]$, where $\vec g:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^2\mid\vec g(x,y,z)=(y-x,z-x)$. How do you calculate the partial derivatives of a composite function, knowing that both $f$ and $\vec g$ are differentiable everywhere?

Comment: $ F(x,y,z) = f(g(x,y,z)) $, so $  \frac{\delta F}{\delta x} = \frac{\delta f}{\delta g}\frac{\delta g}{\delta x} ,  \frac{\delta F}{\delta y} = \frac{\delta f}{\delta g}\frac{\delta g}{\delta y} ,  \frac{\delta F}{\delta z} = \frac{\delta f}{\delta g}\frac{\delta g}{\delta z}$ . I don't know... Edit: But this fuction $ F(x,y,z) = f(g(x,y,z)) $ i so wrong... I mean it can't be define like that

Comment: "Maybe", sorry, I cannot understand 100% your notation. For example, if $h=f(\vec g)$ by chain Rule, then $h_x=f_x(\vec g)\cdot\vec g_x$. Can you continue?

Comment: $ \frac{\delta F}{\delta x} =  \frac{\delta f}{\delta u}\frac{\delta u}{\delta x} =  ((\frac{1}{12}(y-x)^4 - \frac{1}{6}(y-x)^3(y+z)+ \frac{1}{2}(y-x)^2yz) (\frac{1}{12}x^4 - \frac{1}{6}x^3(y+z)+ \frac{1}{2}x^2yz)' $. Still don't know how to do it... Can u give me solution for one 
partial differential?

Comment: I would do $$u_x(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{1}{12}x^4\right)_x -\left( \frac{1}{6}x^3(y+z)\right)_x+ \left(\frac{1}{2}x^2yz\right)_x+\overbrace{f_x(y-x,z-x)\cdot\big((y-x)_x,\;(z-x)_x\big)}^{\text{By Chain Rule}}=\\\frac4{12}x^3-\frac36(y+z)x^2+\frac22xyz+f_x(y-x,z-x)\cdot(-1,-1).$$